# $(a^n-1)(b^n-1)$ can't be a square for all $n$ unless $ab$ is a square

Tags: limits, elementary-number-theory, perfect-powers

Let $a,b$ be positive integers $>1$ such that $(a^n-1)(b^n-1)$ is a square for all $n\ge 1$. Prove that $ab$ is a perfect square.

I'm not asking for a solution to this problem because I already know one. What I'm asking is would the following approach work? or rather I want a particular limit to equal zero.

Assume $(a^n-1)(b^n-1)$ is a perfect square $\forall n\ge1$ and let $x_n=\sqrt{(a^n-1)(b^n-1)}$. Note that $x_n\in \mathbb N $ Now $$x_{n+2}=\sqrt{(a^{n+2}-1)(b^{n+2}-1)}=ab\sqrt{\left(a^{n}-\frac{1}{a^2}\right)\left(b^{n}-\frac{1}{b^2}\right)}$$
and $ab\cdot x_n=ab\sqrt{(a^n-1)(b^n-1)}$. Define $d_n=abx_n-x_{n+2}$ and let us assume for the moment $$\lim_{n\to \infty}d_n=\lim_{n\to \infty}abx_n-x_{n+2}=0$$
Therefore $(d_n)$ converges to $0$, but $d_n\in \mathbb N $ hence $d_n$ is eventually $0$. Meaning for big enough $N$, we have $\forall n\ge N$ $$d_n=abx_n-x_{n+2}=0$$
in other words $abx_n=x_{n+2}$. From this I think there is a lot of ways to get a contradiction but this is what I did,

$$\forall n\ge N' \quad  ab\mid x_{n}\mid x_n^2=(a^n-1)(b^n-1)=(ab)^n-a^n-b^n+1$$
which means $a\mid ab\mid a^n+b^n-1\implies a\mid b^n-1$. In particular $$\forall p\ge N' \quad b^p\equiv  1\pmod a$$
Where $p$ is a prime. But this implies $\operatorname{ord}_ab\mid p$ hence $r=\operatorname{ord}_ab=1$ or $p$. Using the very same method we can see $s=\operatorname{ord}_ba=1$ or $p$ both gives a contradiction. If one of $r$ or $s$ is $p$ the contradiction is immediate since $p\mid \phi(a)$ or $\phi(b)$ but clearly this not okay for large enough $p$. Thus both of $r$ and $s$ is $1$. But this means $$a\mid b-1 \text { and } b\mid a-1$$ Hence $a+b\le a+b-2\implies 0\le -2$ a contradiction.

I think that the solution doesn't contain errors (If it did tell me). The only thing that I'm not sure of is $\lim d_n=0$ because I just counldn't evaluate $$\lim_{n\to \infty}\sqrt{(a^n-1)(b^n-1)}-\sqrt{\left(a^{n}-\frac{1}{a^2}\right)\left(b^{n}-\frac{1}{b^2}\right)}$$
You can clearly multiply by the conjugate but after expanding you get $-\infty /\infty$.

Comment: FYI, using an [Approach0 search](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24(a%5En-1)(b%5En-1)%24%2C%20OR%20content%3A%24ab%24%2C%20OR%20content%3Asquare%2C%20OR%20content%3Apositive%20integers&p=1) found [proving that $ab$ is a perfect square.](/q/275010) (for which you provided an [answer](/a/4564320) almost $2$ months ago), the somewhat stronger [$a,b$ are integers , both greater than $1$ , such that $(a^n-1)(b^n-1)$ is a perfect square for every positive integer $n$ , then $a=b$?](/q/1209961), ...

Comment: (cont.) and the fairly closely related AoPS thread (but currently with no answer) of [About ISL 2009 N7](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h1642569p10354131).

Comment: @JohnOmielan As I said I know an approach. My question is whether the approach I used above is correct.

Comment: I realize @PNT that you're asking specifically about your approach, which is one of the main reasons why I prefixed what I wrote with "FYI". Also note that I'm including what I commented on not necessarily just for you, but also for anybody else who may read your question and would like to know more about the specific problem, including other approaches used to solve it (and to at least know about the other similar question in the AoPS thread I linked to). Nonetheless, I'm sorry regarding any confusion my comments created.

Comment: @JohnOmielan Sorry I didn't know what is FYI.

Comment: Since FYI is a quite commonly used abbreviation for "For Your Information", I use it fairly often in my comments just assuming that people generally already know about it. Thank you for explaining the reason behind your comment (I appreciate the apology, but IMHO (In My Humble Opinion) it's not really needed in this case). Also, I appreciate you reminding me that most people (including myself, of course, for at least some abbreviations) don't know all of the even relatively commonly used abbreviations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The limit of $d_n$ is not zero except if $a=1$ or $b=1$. Assume that $b \ge a \ge 2$. Then,

\begin{align*}
\sqrt{\Big(a^n-\frac{1}{a^2}\Big)\Big(b^n-\frac{1}{b^2}\Big)} & \ge \sqrt{\Big(a^n-\frac{1}{4}\Big)\Big(b^n-1\Big)} \\
& \ge \sqrt{(a^n-1)(b^n-1) + \frac{3}{4}(b^n-1)} \\
& \ge \sqrt{(a^n-1)(b^n-1)} + \frac{3(b^n-1)}{8\sqrt{(a^n-1)(b^n-1) + \frac{3}{4}(b^n-1)}}\\
& \ge \sqrt{(a^n-1)(b^n-1)} + \frac{3(b^n-1)}{8\sqrt{\frac{7}{4}(b^n-1)(b^n-1)}} \mbox{ as $b \ge a$}\\
& \ge \sqrt{(a^n-1)(b^n-1)} + \frac{3}{4\sqrt{7}}
\end{align*}

where the third inequality comes from: $\sqrt{x+y} - \sqrt{x} = \frac{y}{\sqrt{x+y}+\sqrt{x}}$ so $\sqrt{x+y} \ge \sqrt{x} + \frac{y}{2\sqrt{x+y}}$.

Comment: Remark: this is not a sharp lower bound at all.

Comment: What happend in the fourth inequality? You said $b\ge a$ but  I don't where the $7/4$ came from.

Comment: In the sum, I use $(a^n-1)(b^n-1)\le (b^n-1)^2$ for the first term (since $b\ge a$), and $\frac{3}{4}(b^n-1)\le \frac{3}{4}(b^n-1)^2$ for the second one. I use these two inequalities in order to get rid of the square root and get a $b^n-1$ term in the denominator. And $\frac{7}{4}=1+\frac{3}{4}$ just comes from summing the two terms

Comment: Asymptotically, you could also lower bound the limit of the difference by $\frac{3}{8}$ instead of $\frac{3}{4\sqrt{7}}$, by noting that $\frac{3}{4}(b^n-1)$ is negligible compared to $(b^n-1)^2$

Comment: That's not the case: roughly, if $a<b$, instead of using $a^n-1\le b^n-1$, you can lower bound the difference by something that diverges